# https with Sql Reporting Services

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

I have an asp.net webform application.  One of the page has a reportviewer control.  The report is opened in a separate window from SSRS on the page_load event of the webform. The webform application is using HTTPS. However, the SSRS refuses to connect.  When I manually enter the exact url in the browser address bar in the newly opened window, the report shows up correctly.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem opening an http page under the https page.
in order to modify you can open your reportserver under https port 443 with an SSL